# MySQL does not start on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

I downloaded the dmg for MySQL 5.7.10 from the official website (mysql.com). I installed it (meanwhile I even reinstalled a couple times) on my Mac running OS X El Capitan. The menu in the system settings for mysql appears and looks like this: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151226/p78qwlnj.png

When I click on "Start MySQL Server", I'm asked to enter my admin password but after that really nothing happens. I cannot find any log files too, maybe someone can tell where to find them on a Mac?

I don't use any ready-web-server softwares like XAMPP or MAMP.

Hopefully someone can help, merry christmas!

Comment: Nothing will happen. You need to download a client to start using your database.

Comment: well something happens

Comment: @MaxPD It still says the MySQL Server Instance in stopped. Do you mean something like phpmyadmin by client?